# Spring boot doesn't run unit tests

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot

How can I run unit tests for spring boot application while building and deploying using `spring boot:run` command.

My expectation is to have all my unit tests executed before running application, but I dont want to make another maven command like `mvn test` before.

My problem:
I made a simple spring boot application and I could'd find a way to run unit tests while running application from intellij or from command line. Firstly I thought that maybe I have wrong configuration or wrong names of test classess or maybe wrong project structure. So I created spring boot application from intellij template. To my happiness it had already default test written so I simply run application. Unfortunatelly test was not executed.

This is a screenshot of project structure, pom.xml, main class and unit test created by intellij.[Project created by intetelij](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5J8OW.png)

I changed the test runner and test to fail and tried again. Same result.
[unit test changed to fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7vpg.png)

I googled what is hidden underneath `spring boot:run` command here
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/run-mojo.html

I found something interesting at the top of manual: "Invokes the execution of the lifecycle phase test-compile prior to executing itself." So my understanding is that this command only compiles tests but not run them? If So, the question is - Is it possible to add "test" phase by adding some flag to the command?

Comment: You want to achieve something which is completly unusable. Productive code is one part, test code the other. The spring boot only uses the productive code. Usually one uses the unit tests for verifying the correctness of the productive code during the build/deploy process. Why do you want to run the unit tests in production? You maybe misunderstood here something.

Comment: Maybe I didn't state my problem clearly. The only thing I am looking for is to have unit tests executed before running normal spring boot app. For all my maven projects I just made mvn clean install and tests were executed before deploying application. Now I want to do the same. 
As far as I know when running spring boot application using `spring boot:run` all project is firstly compiled before deploy.So is there any possibility to run unit tests also before deploying app? I am aware that I can run `mvn test` before `spring boot:run` but I am just curious if I could do It using one command :)

Comment: What stops you from executing  `mvn test spring-boot:run` ? In IntelliJ you can create Maven Run configuration which will execute it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem here is to do with the maven lifecycle.  According to the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/run-mojo.html) for the `spring-boot:run`, it binds to the lifecyle phase `validate` by default, and invokes the phase `test-compile` before executing.

What you're asking for is to *execute* the tests before running the application.  You could do this with a custom maven profile in your POM - something like the following.

```
<project>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>test-then-run</id>
            <build>
                <defaultGoal>verify</defaultGoal>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>spring-boot-run</id>
                                <phase>verify</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <inherited>false</inherited>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        ...
    </profiles>
...
</project>
```

With this in your POM, you could then run the tests and start the app with:

```
mvn -P test-then-run
```

This binds the `run` goal to the `verify` phase instead of the `validate` phase, which means that the tests will be run first.  You can see which order the phases are run here: https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-core/lifecycles.html

Answer (score 0):

I knew that I could use mvn test before running application. In fact it can be achieved by many ways in intellij. For me, I just add mvn goal test before launching application:

[image]

spring boot configuration in intellij.
 But of course it may be done differently.

The thing is, I was just very curious whether I could somehow manipulate spring boot:run command by using some flag or sth else to get same results but its impossible.

**olambert**, thank You for Your answer too, it works very well.

Comment: if you are satisfied with answers please upvote all helpfull answers and accept best answer.

Comment: unfortunatelly I don't have enough reputation points to have my upvotes being displayed publicly. :)

Comment: Indeed 15 rep is required for that. https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

A few meaningfull edits (correcting typos, tags, formatting) will quickly get you required 15 reputation:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation
Answering question is even better:) Good luck using StackOverflow!