# Spring Boot Maven plugin run goal doesn't invoke tests

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

Following command doesn't run any of my tests :

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

whereas plain old `mvn test` does.

I have added these annotations to the tests :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
```

I do not see any relevant information on the plugin documentation pages, either [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html) or [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/maven-plugin/)

Comment: To be sure, look in your pom if it is not specified that it is to skip the tests.

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983156/spring-boot-doest-run-unit-tests. Basically, it's to do with the default lifecycle phases, and what phase this goal binds to by default and invokes before executing. It's all in your plugin documentation link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring boot maven plugin

> Requires a Maven project to be executed. Requires dependency
>   resolution of artifacts in scope: test. Since version: 1.1. Binds by
>   default to the lifecycle phase: validate. Invokes the execution of the
>   lifecycle phase test-compile prior to executing itself.

[More details](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/run-mojo.html)

Maven lifecycles:

> validate compile test ...

[More details](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)

To sum up: `spring-boot:run` only compiles tests and execute maven validate phase. One of the possible solutions to execute tests before start of the application: `mvn test spring-boot:run`